# Getting Error in android's XML file

Tags: android

Exception raised during rendering: 
    String index out of range: 0
    Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
    The following classes could not be found:
    - TextView (Change to android.widget.TextView, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

```
Getting this Error when i open graphic layout of XML file. Help me in resolving this.
```

Comment: Post your XML please.

Comment: You're using   Button's background as:       `android:background="@layout/button_style"` What is button_style? If it's a style, shift the code to styles.xml or if it is a selector then move it to drawables. Same goes for `tableleftborder`. And then add `android:textStyle="normal"` in your First TextView.

Comment: It's a selector. N moved to drawables. But still not working. ANy other suggestion?

Comment: Lovely man.. Thanks a lot.. It's Done :) :) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using Button's background as: `android:background="@layout/button_style"`

What is `button_style`? If it's a style, shift the code to `styles.xml` **or** if it is a `selector` then move it to `drawables`. Same goes for `tableleftborder` in TextView.

Secondly, add `android:textStyle="normal"` in your First TextView OR simply remove it to make it something like the following:

```
       <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="UGD Demand Details"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

The first textView in the Header RelativeLayout has a `android:textStyle=""` also the RelativeLayout inside the scrollView has `android:height="match_parent"` this should be "wrap_content"

Comment: Changed  it Dominic. Still the same exception.

Comment: android:textStyle=""  i removed this attribute from your code and also all the android:background="@layout/button_style" and tableleftborder and the error disappeared